# gcc appends char* and char as raw pointers ("str" + 'c')

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

What is the reason that gcc adds char* (e.g. "STRING") and char (e.g. 'C') as pointers?

```
  const char *ccc = "Test1";
  const char t = 'T';
  const char *res = ccc + t;
  printf("%s, %p, %d, %p\n", res, ccc, t, res);
```

outputs

```
  , 0x8048d97, 84, 0x8048deb
```

I mean, can you point to the documentation, standard specs, or an article? Can I control or disable this behavior?

UPD: Why I ask and what is unexpected, is that

```
  CString() + 'c'
```

works as

```
 (char*)CString() + (char)char_var
```

when compiler cannot find appropriate operator +. I thought maybe to disable automatic concatenation and find all such places (in legacy code). But mostly I just wanted to find exact documentation for the behavior.

Comment: Why would you want to control or disable this behavior? What would you expect this to do?

Comment: `strcat` might be of some use here.

Comment: This is just how C and C++ treat pointers. If you want operator overloading, use `std::string`. In fact, use `std::string` anyway!

Comment: If you want a standard, buy ISO9899 and ISO14882 in the versions that apply to your environment. This it the fundamental pointer arithmetics that C and C++ are based on. There is no magic added to C types just because you compile it as C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `ccc + t`, `t` is treated as an integer. The net effect is that `res` points to `ccc` plus 84 bytes, where 84 is the ASCII code of `'T'`.

It is worth pointing out that `ccc + t` operates purely on the pointers, and does not touch the actual string. I am saying this in case there's any expectation that `"Test" + 'T'` might *append* the character to the string -- it does not.

Answer (score 1):

It's called pointer arithmetic. For example `ptr + x` is equivalent to `&ptr[x]`.

Answer (score 1):

*C does not have strings*.  C has arrays and pointers.

You should think of the "string constant" `"Test1"` as *syntactic sugar* for the array initializer `{ 'T', 'e', 's', 't', '1', 0x00 }`.

*C does not even have characters*. C has small (eight-bit, usually) integers.

You should think of the "character constant" `'T'` as *syntactic sugar* for the numeric constant `0x54` (assuming ASCII).

So when you write

```
const char *ccc = /* whatever */;
char t = /* whatever */;
const char *res = ccc + t;
```

you're adding a small positive integer to a pointer.  No more, no less.

I would offer advice on how to do the thing you wanted to do, but it would be tedious and verbose and distract from the point.  C++ has a decent string class these days, you will probably be happier just learning that.

Comment: "C does not have strings" So why do you think C Standard defines a *string* as: "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character"?

Comment: Of course the standard defines the interpretation of that syntactic sugar for array initializers that I mentioned.  And there are a bunch of standard library functions that use the same convention, that also need definitions.  It is a long way from there to actually having a first-class string type in the language.